# In "Clean Code," how do variable number of arguments affect whether the function is monad, dyad or triad?

Tags: java, function, coding-style, parameter-passing

I m reading book "Clean code". It has this paragraph about variable arguments passed to functions and how to name functions, args.

> Argument Lists
>   Sometimes we want to pass a variable number of arguments into a function. Consider, for example, the String.format method:

```
String.format("%s worked %.2f hours.", name, hours);
```

> If the variable arguments are all treated identically, as they are in the example above, then they are equivalent to a single argument of type List. By that reasoning, String.format is actually dyadic. Indeed, the declaration of String.format as shown below is clearly dyadic.

```
public String format(String format, Object... args)
```

> So all the same rules apply. Functions that take variable arguments can be monads, dyads, or even triads. But it would be a mistake to give them more arguments than that.

```
void monad(Integer... args);
void dyad(String name, Integer... args);
void triad(String name, int count, Integer... args);
```

monad - function with one arg, dyad, dyadic - function with 2 args, triad - 3 args.

Can someone explain the passage? The only thing i got is this:

even if you have many arguments of same type, you can put them in one List, example - Integer ...args means many int arguments passed.
And at the same time, a programmer should still follow same recommendation - write functions that have no more than 3 arguments, dyadic functions can still have 2 arguments by showing  arguments of same type as Object ...args.

Am i correct, or is there any other meaning in this passage?

Comment: *Why* does the author think 'it would be a mistake to give them more arguments than that'. What kind of mistake? Does he give a *reason?*

Comment: he advocates that functions can ONLY have 3 args at most! more args results in reduced clarity and readability

Comment: In that case I would get a better book. Computer programming is hard enough without setting arbitrary boundaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author is just trying to say to count a variable argument like `Integer...` as a single argument when counting whether a function is monad, dyad, or triad. The reasoning is it's de facto equivalent to passing a `List`. (It's actually passed as an array, so I'm not sure why the author is talking about `List`).

If the author is recommending a function not exceed 3 arguments, then the author is saying `foo(Integer, String, Object...)` is okay, whereas `foo(Integer, String, Long, Object...)` is not.

Comment: not the point but `Integer...` = `Integer[]` array which is not a `List`

Comment: Oh.. didn't see that you were just using his words. Maybe the book isn't assuming Java exclusively, the principles are the same everywhere and the specific meaning of `List` is not universal.